# Video streaming cloudfront

Tags: 6, media

I am administering a drupal 6 website for a small company. We want to offer our customers restricted streaming video content on the drupal site.

What I heard it is a good idea to place these type of media files on a cdn service, everybody keeps recommending amazon s3 / cloudfront.

Is it possible to have the files on amazon, but have a restricted area on my website, where the user needs to enter some login information and after being authenticated can view the content?

If it is possible, how, what are your recommendations?

I am not familiar with using cdn, so sorry if I ask something very simplistic (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Video module](http://drupal.org/project/video) supports storing videos on Amazon S3. Restricting node access can be done by creating a special content type for your videos and only giving view access for that content type to a role that you assign to some users, possibly by using the [Content Access module](http://drupal.org/project/content_access).